# Is the second moment enough to characterize the Brownian motion?

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, malliavin-calculus

In the page 14 of the book ["The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-28329-3) from Nualart one reads:

[image]

I understand that if $Z_t \sim N(0,t)$ then

$$\Bbb{E}[Z_t^{2k}] = \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}t^k$$

However, I can't see why this follows from the single fact that $\Bbb{E}[(W_t-W_s)^2] = t-s$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $i$, he defines $\{W^i(t), t \in \mathbb{R}^+\}$ to be a zero-mean Gaussian process with covariance function $E[W^i(s)W^i(t)] = s \wedge t$.  This means that we know that $W^i(t) - W^i(s)$ is a normal random variable with mean zero; therefore, once we know what it's variance is, we've characterized the distribution entirely.  The point of this section is to use Kolmogorov's continuity criterion to show that we can make $W^i$ continuous almost surely.

---

EDIT: Here's a process that has independent increments, mean zero, and the variance of increments is $t - s$ but isn't Brownian motion:

Consider a Poisson process on $\mathbb{R}^+$ with intensity $1$, and let $X_t$ denote the number of points in $[0,t]$.  Define $Z_t = X_t - t$.  Then $$\mathbb{E}[(Z_t - Z_s)^2] = \mathbb{E}[((X_t - X_s) - (t-s))^2] = \mathrm{Var}[\mathrm{Poisson}(t-s)] = t-s$$

Comment: The question is rather if the term THIS is this implies refers to the property stated immidiatly above. In that case we don't have the Gaussian distribution at our disposal. I agree with you that if you have the Gaussian property you can conclude the result, but that is not the point of the question.

Comment: @Conrado, of course not every distribution with second moment equal to $ t-s $ has higher moments equal to that.  The way he comes to this conclusion in his text is that the defines $W^i$ to be a Gaussian process with the correct covariance, and then tried to prove continuity.  So he *does* have the Gaussian structure at his disposal.

Comment: Do you have a counter example? That is, can you define a process on the space of trajectories such that $X_t - X_s$ has second moment $t-s$ that is not the Brownian motion?

Comment: @ConradoCosta, I'm not sure, I haven't tried to think of one, but that's a separate question from what Nualart does: he defines a Gaussian process and then *shows* it's a trajectory (i.e. continuous).  I haven't yet thought about whether every such trajectory must be Brownian motion, but that isn't what's happening in this text.

Comment: I think it is, But I am glad you claim otherwise. When he says THIS, in "This implies that"   a naive reader, as me for example, might think that this refers to the display that comes just before on the text. So this leads to the question... I suspect the answer is yes.... that is that if you satisfy the second moment condition, then you are Brownian motion... no need to rely on the distribution or covariance properties stated before. So that is my question....

Comment: @ConradoCosta, But read the section before that. Nowhere does he assume that it's continuous, so it wouldn't even be correct to call it a trajectory.  He's **proving** that it's continuous.  I'm not sure what to tell you: he *defines* $W^i$ to be Gaussian, so, yes, the second moment of the increments being $t - s$ do imply that the higher moments are that.

Comment: I understand Kolmogorov continuity theorem. I call trajectory without implying it is continuous, I am well aware of the fact that so far it is not a continuous process. My question, If I may state it again is to What is THIS in the sentence "This implies that" referring to. Imagine it refers only to the display that comes above... In that case  is it sufficient to deduce the higher values of the moments? I suspect that the answer is yes. But I suspect that you might have a counter example. In which case, can you explain it?

Comment: @ConradoCosta, I added a counterexample that has the given variances but isn't Brownian motion.